# cytoscape.js: wrong mouse pointer position after container change

Tags: cytoscape.js

I use cytoscape.js 2.2.5 to draw a graph in an angular.js app and I can properly select nodes. When the `<div>` with the graph moves, the mouse pointer position on the canvas is not updated. That means I have to click on the 'old' position of a node to select it.

I tried `cy.reset()`, `cy.center()` and `cy.fit()`, but the mouse pointer position doesn't change.

How can I update the graph after I change the position of the cytoscape `<div>`?

### Original page:

[image]

### After change of `<div>` position

When I remove the blue panel and the graph `<div>` moves up, the mouse pointer position is wrong. I use the ng-show directive (which uses css hidden/visible).
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you resize (or move, I suppose) the cy div, you need to notify the core of the change.  Unfortunately, the browser DOM model doesn't have a way to track this automatically.

```
cy.resize(); // notify that the container has changed dims
```

http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#core/viewport-manipulation/cy.resize

Perhaps `cy.resize()` should have an alias like `cy.invalidateDimensions()` so it's clear you need it for your usecase.

Comment: `cy.resize()` works in 2.2.4 but doesn't work in 2.2.5 or 2.2.6. I didn't change anything in the code except referencing 2.2.4.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the bug! Next time I'll raise a github issue ;)

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I just ran into this also and was able to resolve by using version 2.2.7. For others, make sure you go download the latest version to avoid this.